# Scrape site with login details with bs4 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to login in website with bs4. Login is done but when I try to parse shop data it shows that I'm not login.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.session() as c: 
    
    link="https://www.tais-shoes.ru/wp-login.php" 
    initial=c.get(link) 

    login_data = {"log": "*****","pwd": "*****", 
              "rememberme": "forever", 
              "redirect_to": "https://www.tais-shoes.ru/my-account/", 
              "redirect_to_automatic": "1"
             }

    page_login = c.post('https://www.tais-shoes.ru/wp-login.php', data=login_data)
    
    print(page_login) 
    
    shop_url = "https://www.tais-shoes.ru/shop/"
    html = requests.get(shop_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    print(soup)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the instance of the `request.Session` you've created, but down below in your code you create a new connection with `requests.get`.

Change this

```
    html = request.get(shop_url)
```

To this:

```
    html = c.get(shop_url)
```

Full code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as c: 
    
    link="https://www.tais-shoes.ru/wp-login.php" 
    initial=c.get(link) 

    login_data = {"log": "*****","pwd": "*****", 
              "rememberme": "forever", 
              "redirect_to": "https://www.tais-shoes.ru/my-account/", 
              "redirect_to_automatic": "1"
             }

    page_login = c.post('https://www.tais-shoes.ru/wp-login.php', data=login_data)
    
    print(page_login) 
    
    shop_url = "https://www.tais-shoes.ru/shop/"
    html = c.get(shop_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    print(soup)
```